# ws error Invalid data, chunk must be a string or buffer, not object

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I have a TypeScript project with `ws` as a WebSocket Server like this:

```
        this.wss = new WebSocket.Server({ port: 9020 });

    this.wss.on('connection', function connection(ws, req) {

        this.webs = ws;
        console.log(req);
        ws.on('message', function incoming(message) {

            console.log('received: %s', message);

            ws.send('something');

            console.log("Send Changed Message");
        });
    });
```

The websocket connection is set up properly but when the 'send' is triggered it gives the following error in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Invalid data, chunk must be a string or buffer, not object
```

I follow the debugger and my string is send properly into all the functions as a UInt8Array but at a certain point it expects a string or buffer. I took these functions from the sample code.

What do I have to do to make ws send this string properly?

Comment: What are you sending? This works fine for me: http://jsbin.com/dicazuqeva/edit?js,output

Comment: just a string 'something'